# My app won't show up in my app drawrer

Tags: android, manifest

I made an app that (just recently) stopped showing up in my app drawrer. It shows up as an installed app in Titanium Backup, but when I select it, it does not give me a "run app" option. The only way I am able to run it is by running it in Android Studio. I am pretty sure i have messed something up in my manifest that is making it act weird. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my manifest? I have been comparing it to many different manifests and I tried removing and changing several lines in it but no luck.
I am by far no expert in development therefore if the problem I am having is due to a very small error that I may not understand, be easy on me.

Here is my manifest. This is a text messaging app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.sms"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="sms" />
                    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

        <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".QuickReply"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>





</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two different `intent-filter`, one for the `android.intent.action.MAIN` action and one for the `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.action.SENDTO` actions.

Change your `AndroidManifest.xml` from this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="sms"/>
        <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
        <data android:scheme="mms"/>
        <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```